# Joined point on Bing Maps in MacOS Chrome

Tags: macos, google-chrome, bing-maps

I'm using Bind Maps to display my locations on map.

In case there are more than 3,000 locations on map in MacOS Chrome browser it is displayed in strange way (see screenshot).

Is it browser problem or Bing Maps problem?

[image]

---

UPD : Using Bing Maps V7

---

UPD 2 : As I am using not images for pushpins but style them via css, I've added to points `border solid`. I've tried to change border-type, and after this it seems like "Art Work" is disabled.

Comment: Never seen this one before. Will pass on to dev team to see if they can reproduce this. Likely a Chrome issue. Note that V8 only supports Safari on MacOS.

Comment: @rbrundritt, Currently I'm using V7. Don't have time to move to V8 yet

Comment: Then this is definitely a Chrome issue on MacOS.